# How do you select an element from a list and prependto?

Tags: jquery

I wish to hoverover one list item and preperndTo the destination DIV.

But they all prependTo into the destination DIV.

```
  $('ul li a').each(function () {
        $(this).mouseover(function () {
            $('ul li ul').prependTo('#destination');
        });
});
```

How do you specify one item at a time??

http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/zpdAy/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpdAy/7/)

```
$("ul li a").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).next().prependTo('#destination'); // or sibling('ul')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle. [See updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zpdAy/3/).

Basically, I just changed the `each` in this line:

```
$('ul li a').each(function () {
```

To use `one` instead:

```
$('ul li a').one(function () {
```

Not sure if that is the behavior you are after...

Comment: There's no need to use the loop at all.

Comment: Agreed! Now the OP has several answers to choose from anyway.

Comment: Except `.one()` does something completely different to `.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem. There's no need to use `each()` by the way:

```
$('ul li a').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).nextSibling().prependTo('#destination');
});
```

[See the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpdAy/6/).